# Initializing multiple pointers with same value with single initialization in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I want to declare two or more pointers with same value with a single assignment operator in C/C++? The following code is an example:

```
List* a = NULL; 
List* b = NULL;
List* c = NULL;
```

Is there an equivalent in one line?

Edit: To clarify, I am looking for answer in both languages. I used a 'slash(/)' to separate out in the case of people willing to answer for one language. Thanks.

Comment: Pick ***a*** language.

Comment: "with a single assignment operator"? Do not trade initialization for assignment. And no, it can't be done with a single operator.

Comment: @AnT you are right on the initialization. Thanks. It's updated.

Comment: _Any_ value or just null?

Comment: Any similar value.

Answer (score 5):

```
List *a = NULL, *b = NULL, *c = NULL;
```

or

```
List *a, *b, *c;
a = b = c = NULL;
```

Note that in C++11 you should avoid the `NULL` macro in favor of `nullptr`.

Comment: Why "or `0`"??? "Classic" `NULL` in C++ **is** `0`. And `0` suffers from the same problems as `NULL`, which is why `nullptr` was introduced in the first place. Moreover, since `NULL` can be defined as `nullptr`, the two best alternatives would actually be `nullptr` (best) and `NULL`, while `0` is the worst one that should be avoided.

Comment: Also, this is still three assignment operators, not one.

Comment: @AnT, Bjarne had his reasons for preferring 0 when he wrote [his FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null). In any case, `nullptr` is the clear winner.

Comment: @chris: Firstly, his reasons are purely superficial and personally-preferential (ther are no technical reasons to prefer `0` over `NULL`), so it desn't mean much. Secondly, his reasons were completely invalidated and obsoleted by C++11. `0` is now the *worst* option of the three and the reasons for that are *technical*, not personally-preferential.  And the above poster is talking about C++11. The Bjarne's FAQ entry in now a historical oddity. It is no longer valid.

Comment: @AnT Fair enough, I changed it.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, there are no assignments in your example - they are initialisations, since all three lines are declarations (actually, definitions in most contexts).

It is possible to wrap the example into a single line

```
 List *a = NULL, *b = NULL, *c = NULL;
```

but note that this repeats usage of "= NULL" for initialisation of each.   Also note the need for extra asterisks (`*`) as, without these, not all the variables would be pointers.    Note that placing multiple declarations or definitions in one line like this is considered poor style, since it is easy to forget one of the `*` or one of the initialisers, and get completely different results than intended  (unitialised `auto` variables are not initialised to zero).

If you are willing to separate the declaration from initialisation, it is possible to do

```
 List *a, *b, *c;
 a = b = c = NULL;
```

If the definitions are globals, the default initialisation is zero, so

```
 // assume at file scope (outside any function)

 List *a;
 List *b;
 List *c;

 //  equivalently:   List *a, *b, *c;
```

does initialise all three to `NULL`.      However this doesn't work work for initialising to other (non-zero) values.    Within a function (or block) the same can be achieved by preceding the above with `static`.

In C++11, it is possible to do

```
 List *a{}, *b{}, *c{};
```

Instead of using three named variables, it is possible to use an array.

```
 List *a[3] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

which can be simplified to

```
 List *a[3] = {NULL};
```

since the missing initialisers in this case will result in the corresponding elements being initialised to zero.

In C++11 and later (only) the array initialisation can - as pointed out by AnT in comment - be simplified to

```
 List *a[3] = {};
```

or to

```
 List *a[3]{};
```

In C++, it is often encouraged (unlike in C) to replace all usages of `NULL` with `0` or (from C++11) with `nullptr`.

Comment: ... which can be simplified even further into `List *a[3] = {};` or even `List *a[3]{};`

Comment: At least for C this `List *a[3] = {NULL};` (if not in global scope) not necessarily initialises the 2nd and 3rd element to `NULL`. It sets their bytes to binary `0`s, yes, but `NULL`s  binary representation does not need to be `0`s.

Comment: @alk - not so.  The second and third elements are initialised to zero for the appropriate type (i.e. `List *`).  For any pointer type, the value of zero is the `NULL` pointer, regardless of what the binary representation of `NULL` is.

Comment: @Peter: Correct. Need to clear this wrong assumption out of my head

Answer (score 1):

With c++11, you can do this:

```
int* a{}, *b{}, *c{};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to declare and initialize multiple variables with a single assignment in C.

In C++17, you can get what you want using structured bindings:

```
auto [a, b, c] = std::make_tuple(ptr, ptr, ptr);
```

If you don't want to repeat the initialization value, you can make your own function to create a `tuple` by repeating a value `N` times:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
auto repeat_impl(T const& x, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::make_tuple((Is, x)...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto repeat(T const& x) {
    return repeat_impl(x, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Use like so:

```
auto [a, b, c] = repeat<3>(ptr);
```

Though your specific example of initialization to null can be done using `array`:

```
auto [a, b, c] = std::array<List*, 3>();
```

In C++11, the best you can do is use `tie` to initialize the objects separately from their declarations:

```
List *a, *b, *c;
std::tie(a, b, c) = repeat<3>(ptr);
```